# PropertyChanged is null when binding to static singleton property

Tags: wpf, mvvm

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource BaseViewModel}">
        <DockPanel>
            <TabContro>
                <TabItem DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowsViewModel}">
                    <Tabs:Main />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=Common.IsLoading}">
            <Control Style="{StaticResource BusyAnimationStyle}"/>
        </Popup>
</Grid>
```

And:

```
public class Common : NotificationObject
{
    private static Common _instance = null;

    private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        set
        {
            if (_isLoading != value)
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsLoading);
            }
        }
    }

    protected Common()
    {

    }

    public static Common GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new Common();

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

There is 2 ViewModels
BaseViewModel
MainWindowsViewModel

the BaseViewModel is the father of MainWindow
and BaseViewModel have the common as property

the problem is when MainWindowVM change IsLoading property its not effect
the PropertyChanged is null
Any Solution?

Comment: Nope, can't understand this question.  Could be a bunch of things.  Not enough info to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to bind to IsLoading from Common class, but your binding implies that IsLoading is static but it's not.

You should probably have a binding like this:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static Common.Instance}, Path=IsLoading}
```

You should also use a property to access your singleton:

```
public static Common Instance {
    get {return _instance??(_instance = new Common());}
}
```